# How to hide one html tag behind another at a certain coordinate

Tags: css, html

I have two `div` elements, within the one background `div` I have another `div` which uses CSS animation to display a box going up and down.

I want to make those parts of this div with the box 'disappear' as soon as any part of that box crosses over that background div.

I have an example here [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/56p82/1/), where as soon the red box exceeds the black box it should then go 'under' the black `div` rather than remaining at the top as it's presently.

This is the CSS code:

```
body{
z-index:100;
}
div{
background: black;
height:300px;
}

#scroll{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: test;
-webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
animation-name: test;
animation-duration: 30s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-play-state: running;

}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {left:0px; top:270px;}
100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@keyframes test {
0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {left:0px; top:270px;}
100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

body {
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

What is the best way to create this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent div.

I sped up your animation for testing purposes.

[Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/56p82/2/)

```
#scrollParent{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a z-index to the outer-most background(the white part in the fiddle) and make it higher than the z-index of the red box. Guess that should work.